# Is there any side effect of reducing IIS recycle time interval?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, recycle

My asp .net mvc3 application is hosted in IIS 7 and i wish to reduce memory consumption by reducing the recycle time interval of IIS to 1000 mintes . Is there any side-effects in doings this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No side effects of reducing the recycling time in IIS. It doesn't even consumes much time to do recycle. Recycling saves you from memory leak. For more info check [this link.](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153736.aspx/1)